# Generate and display preview thumbnails for videos html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm working on a video website and I am trying to display preview thumbnails for the videos on a page.

I'm looking for a way to generate and display on hover those mutliple thumbnails for a video. The same way as on adult websites...

Comment: take a look https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-video-fragments-captions-dynamic-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `ffmpeg`, it's pretty efficient and is available for all platforms. This is an example to make thumbnail every 1 minute:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg
```

More examples: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video